# Suppose $f(a)=p$, a prime, then $f$ has a t most three distinct zeros.

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, prime-numbers, roots

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Show that if $f(a)=p$ for some integer $a$ and prime number $p$, then $f(x)$ has at most three integer roots; that is, there are at most three distinct integers $\alpha,\beta,\text{ and }\gamma$ such that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=f(\gamma) = 0$.

Comment: So $f(a)=p$ and $f(a)=0$?

Comment: you used $a$ twice

Comment: Please use MathJax to format and show some efforts.

Comment: Think about the factorisation of $f$.

Comment: If $p=3$ there is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119757/a-polynomial-with-integer-coefficients-that-attains-the-value-5-at-four-distin/1119779#1119779).  If $p$ is any other prime you can easily modify this answer.

Answer (score 1):

David points out the answer in a comment. Let me adapt that answer here:

Suppose $f(x)$ has four roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$. Then
$f(x)=g(x)(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$. Applying to $a$, we find
$$
g(a)(a-\alpha)(a-\beta)(a-\gamma)(a-\delta)=p.
$$
But $(a-\alpha),(a-\beta),(a-\gamma),(a-\delta)$ are four distinct integers, and this is impossible. This is because if $p$ is prime, the maximal amount of distinct integers we can factor it into is $3$, given by multiplying its divisors:
$$ p=(-p)\cdot(-1)\cdot 1$$

Therefore $f$ has at most $3$ roots.